# JFileChooser in a slick2d applet

Tags: java, swing, applet, jfilechooser, slick2d

In my project I have a `JFileChooser` to select the path of which you want to save/load a world from. My project works great when running as an application but when it's on my website (an applet), it glitches.

See, what happens is everything works fine and the file chooser window pops-up BUT when you come to click on it, it does nothing. It's static, you can't type anything, use any keys. Here's an image of what I see.

http://ghostid.net/ran/popupExample.png

I literally have to open task manager and close Java for my browser to work again. Any idea what might be causing this? Why does it work as an application but not as an applet?

I signed my jars too... Could Slick2D be interfering with it? Is the *focus* stuck on the slick applet?

Comment: 1) Ensure the [Java Console](http://www.java.com/en/download/help/javaconsole.xml) is configured to show for applets & JWS apps.  If there is no output at the default level, raise it and try again.  I'd guess this is a security problem, but I don't like guessing.. 2) Also note that I decided not to in-line the image in the question, since it is largely pointless.  It could be summed up as 'the chooser appears, but the applet freezes'.

Comment: It is a security feature of java. java applets cannot access files present in the hard disk.

Comment: This link explains why in detail. http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/deployment/applet/security.html